# Core plot scale

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, core-plot

I want to graph like this.

When I set big yRange, app on IOS simulator and device not run...

```
int xAxisMin = 0;
int xAxisMax = 30;
int yAxisMin = 0;
int yAxisMax = 200000;  

CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(xAxisMin) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(xAxisMax - xAxisMin)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(yAxisMin) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(yAxisMax - yAxisMin)];
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more info. Do you get an error of some sort? If so what does it say.

Comment: I haven't error. if for example yAxisMax = 100 - all good. The problem  that is yAxisMax big value and I think it create graph size 200000x30 = 6000000 operations

Comment: What labeling policy does the y-axis use? The default fixed-interval policy will make a *lot* of labels if you don't set the interval correctly. This can cause the performance problem you're seeing.

Comment: I fixed this, I doing custom labels